# How do I close a folder after I have chosen a game to play?

Tags: windows

I'm a gamer and I have my huge collection of games in one folder. I usually pick a game to play and play it for a while and then I've got to do homework. However, when I quit my game, I see my huge collection of games again and I just decide to keep on playing without doing any homework.

I just need some way to close my games folder as soon as I have picked a game so that I actually get some homework done. Btw, just closing it myself isn't going to work because I forget stuff really easily.

Comment: Get some self-control my friend, it's the only real answer to this problem. ;)  Aside from that, it's be good to know which operating system you're using, and perhaps what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you should be able to control yourself. But I know that feeling ;)

A very simple method would be, to simply close the folder after launching the game.

But well there is another "strange" solution. It's a bit a "workaround", but of course, you don't have to do homework all the time. So if you know, that you have to do homework, you could start the game from `commandline`:

1. Start a `commandline`
2. Navigate to your games-folder

   ```
   cd C:/Path/To/Your/Games
   ```
3. Now start the game by starting the `.exe

   ```
   starcraft2.exe
   ```

This way, you won't see your games-collection.